# É possível disparar dois tipos de ação no Redux ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: react, redux

Estou utilizando o Redux e Redux-saga em uma aplicação com React e com dúvida na hora de exibir o load para o usuário quando uma saga for disparada. Não sei se é uma boa prática, mas estava pensando na possibilidade de disparar 2 actions. 1 para exibição do load e outra para acionar a saga. É possível disparar dois tipos de ação ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 1):

Falando de [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), por mais que você tente, vc só vai conseguir disparar uma action de cada vez, isso porque no [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), as instruções são executadas uma por vez e mesmo que vc use [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) ou o que for, para tratar ações assíncronas, vai continuar sendo uma. Mas isso não quer dizer que elas serão resolvidas na ordem que são executadas.

No seu caso, é bem válida essa abordagem de uma action antes p/ atualizar o estado de loading, uma segunda action p/ fazer um fetch ou outra operação assíncrona e um terceiro p/ mudar o status de loading de novo.

Em se tratando de saga, não faço idéia por que nunca usei. Mas o princípio é o mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado @jan, depois de pesquisar descobri que dentro do saga consigo disparar uma action para o load e após o retorno do ajax posso disparar outra para ocultar o load.